# Is there a way to automatically extract information from emails (e.g. regex prices on gmail)?

Tags: gmail, if-this-then-that, regex

Every month I get an email from my mobile carrier which tells me how much money my contract has cost me the last month, and I'd like to be able to form that into an iOS notification with IFTTT. The problem is that I can't just create a new recipe with the mail body as a title, because the exact cost is not in the first lines for the mail.

An example for a mail I get would be

```
Hello nO_OnE_910,
[text]
cost: 10.00 €
[text]
```

And I'd like to get the information 10.00 € from that, with a regex like `'cost:\s(\d+\.\d{2})\s'` and then send an email with the content of the first group to IFTTT to process the data.

Is this possible in any way without having to have a device on my end running?

Comment: What machine/device would you like to find the regex and send the content to IFTTT? In other words, where would you like to process the email filter?

Comment: If possible I'd like to use no machine at all and make a web app work for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was just looking for a similar feature in IFTTT, but then discovered that Zapier (kind of) supports this. They're not proper regex's but it does pattern matching of sorts

https://parser.zapier.com

Might be good enough for what you need!

Comment: Can you include some basic directions to get to that part of the Zapier application, e.g., "click on the Gmail button and do X," please?

Comment: perfect! Together with the actual zapier service which directly pushes the result it seems to work just fine! thanks!

Comment: This works perfect!

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is: no, you can't do this.

The long answer:

- IFTTT does not have a regular expression scraper, at least as of this tweet:

https://twitter.com/grmeyer/status/240888420677873664

- IFTTT does not legitimately let you create your own THIS conditions or THAT actions.
- Illegitimately, you can use https://github.com/captn3m0/ifttt-webhook to create your own THAT actions. You would still need a server on the Internet or you could try using a free service.
- The flow of action would then be:

  - IFTTT receives a copy of the billing email (either by checking your gmail, or by you auto-fowarding them your copy).
  - IFTTT sends the email to your application.
  - Your application filters out the regex, and sends email to IFTTT.
  - IFTTT parses this new email and turns it into an SMS.

"The technology involved in getting this to work is so mind-bogglingly complex that 999,999,999 times out of a billion it's simpler just to look at the email yourself"

Also consider looking into pipes.yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Zapier for integrating applications: Gmail,
   Google Sheets, Google Contacts:
   a. Connect your Gmail and Google Sheets applications.
   b. Connect your google sheets and Google Contacts applications.
2. Capture a new Gmail message event.
3. Push your message content into Google Sheets.
4. Within google sheets parse your message content using regular expressions. Select the link below to get the RegEx patterns you need:
   https://zapier.com/blog/extract-links-email-phone-regex/#regex
5. Push your Google Columns into Google Contacts.